# Combining Duplicate Classses From different Libs that are the same class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I Have a n-tier application and each layer is a class lib.
DAL -> BLL -> PL
Data Access Layer -> Business Logic Layer -> Presentation Layer

In my PL i Need to reference my wrapper class "Shippers" from the DAL however i want to remove the dependency to my DAL and make it go through my BLL. This forces me to have a duplicate class of my shippers in my BLL.

However How would i link two of the same classes in 2 different Libs?
I also have no clue of what the term of duplicating the same classes is known as?

Here is my Shippers Class

```
public class Shippers
{

    public int ShipperID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "link" two of the same classes? Be specific about what you do now, that is not "linked" and then show what it would be like if it were "linked".

Comment: use full path sintax? somehting like `new path1.class1()` and `new path2.class1()`

Comment: I want my presentation layer to use the shippers class that is in the BLL. And i want that same shippers class to add its data to the shipers class in the DAL.

Comment: And visa versa so the DAL will send a list of shippers List<DAL.Shippers> to the BLL and that will then be passed to the PLL I want the list to be converted to use the BLL.Shippers. Basically its the BLL taking the data the DAL.Shippers has and Adding it to its BLL.SHippers then passing it to the PLL. and then if the PLL is sending data in the form of BLL.Shippers that should be converted to DAL.SHippers on its fly by. Currently the PLL is using DAL.Shippers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, use `Composition` technique and in your `BLL` project add the dll reference of the library which contains `Shippers` class. Bll class have the Shipper as member field and expose a public property/method which returns a instance of `Shipper` and access the same from your `PL DAL`. Like below:

`BLL Project`

```
public class BLL_Some_Class
{
  private Shipper _shipper = new Shipper();

  public Shipper getShipper
     {
       get{ return _shipper; }
      } 
}
```

`PL DAL Project`

```
BLL_Some_Class bll1 = new BLL_Some_Class();
bll1.getShipper;
```

Comment: Thanks il give it a try

Comment: Hi I tried it however its not working with regards to my interfaces please see my original solution with no changes using the DAL.shippers in the PLL

https://mega.co.nz/#!VF8RBSgY!E6fU8HFfNTKKH7VRtvFIy10xa4Cwrf6hryjcP0ylVSg

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a class on BLL and make it inherit from Shippers on DAL, would look something like this in your BLL:

```
public class Shippers:DAL.Shippers
{
}
```

Comment: Inheritance in OO programming basically means duplicating a class functionality and optionally adding upon it.

Comment: I want my presentation layer to use the shippers class that is in the BLL.
And i want that same shippers class to add its data to the shipers class in the DAL.

Comment: And visa versa so the DAL will send a list of shippers List<DAL.Shippers> to the BLL and that will then be passed to the PLL I want the list to be converted to use the BLL.Shippers. 

Basically its the BLL taking the data the DAL.Shippers has and Adding it to its BLL.SHippers then passing it to the PLL. and then if the PLL is sending data in the form of BLL.Shippers that should be converted to DAL.SHippers on its fly by.

Currently the PLL is using DAL.Shippers

Answer (score 0):

So finally i found a solution it was to make a central class lib holding the shipper class. I then used this as a reference to all the PLL and DAL and BL and this would remove the dependency to my DAL from the PLL

Thanks for all the help